# Membrane jacket rises up when crouching

Tags: waterproof-clothing, jackets

I have a trouble with my membrane jacket. When I am crouching or moving around, my jacket rises up in the back and doesn't go down when I stand up straight again. How can I prevent the jacket from doing this?

Comment: @Austris is this problem specific to membrane/nylon jackets? It seems vague and unrelated to outdoor clothing.

Comment: What is a membrane jacket?  Is it like Gortex?  Is it friction that prevents it from falling back in place?  Is the jacket perhaps too tight?

Comment: The jacket probably isn't a proper fit.

Comment: Buy a bigger jacket?!

Comment: If the jacket has some way of tightening the lower hem, then if the hem is too tight, it will rise as you crouch or raise your arms but remain in place when you stand up or lower your arms.

Answer (score 2):

Sew a crotch strap: one end on the back, one on the front with quick release fittings, and length adjustable allowance.

Comment: I am perfectly serious, and have used the device. I own Musto brand foulweather gear for extreme sailing conditions; the "float coat"/PFD liner has a crotch strap to prevent the jacket from going up over my head in the event of going overboard. Also certain stand-alone PFD's use a crotch strap.